# Incorrect badges displaying in profile

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

I've stumbled across a user whose [profile](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/users/5338/sina-arzany) mentions they've got two 'Famous Question' gold badges:

[image]

Upon clicking the 'Famous Question' link, we see this:

[image]

Even more curious, they appear to have bronze badges from before the site was [even created](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61013/coffee).

As I was writing up this post, the badge counts appear to have been corrected.

Is this a case of an account merge gone wrong?

Comment: I can confirm that this did happen and I also have a screenshot of it. I'm not sure what caused it and I'm curious to find out... I'm not sure if it's related but at the same time this was happening, SFF's tags page was returning the tag list from SO.

Comment: Yeah that looks like the system was querying Stack Overflow for a bunch of pages (that user ID [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5338/jason-francis?tab=profile) has those exact badges). Appears to have been fixed though.

Comment: @Catija can we please see that screenshot to help us dig?

Comment: @MarcGravell it's at work but I'll get it to you when I get there. I posted a cropped version in the TL but I should be able to recover the full window if that helps.

Comment: @MarcGravell https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx2Um.png Originally noticed at 12:39 UTC fixed by 12:51 UTC. Rand *may* have a screenshot of SFF being weird... not sure.